# Tern doesn't go to definition in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tern

I'm using Tern IDE 0.9 for Javascript on Eclipse 4.4 in windows.
When pressing on a function with CTRL + Click, instead of going to definition it opens a window and asks me if i want to choose

> Open an editor on the selected
>   Tern - go to definition

When choosing the second option, it doesn't do anything.
On a clean Eclipse without any plugins except the Tern IDE, it works.
Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

You have two commands both bound to the Ctrl+Click key stroke.

Open the Preferences and look in 'General > Keys' for the clashing commands. You can click on the 'Binding' column to sort by the binding which should help to find the clash.

Change one of the clashing bindings to something else to remove the issue.

Comment: couldnt find any clashing CTRL keys. i've exported the list of keys http://pastebin.com/Vnmisf3r can you please assist?